# Installing Sense / NET Error ContentRegistrationException UnknownContentHandler SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.ADSync.ADSettings

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to install SN evaluation edition on my machine (Win. Server 2012 R2 Datacenter) and I end with the following error:

```
2017-02-13 11:34:08.2961    XsltApplicationCtd.xml ... Ok
2017-02-13 11:34:08.2961    YesNoFieldSettingCtd.xml ... Ok
2017-02-13 11:34:08.2961    
2017-02-13 11:34:08.2961    Installing content types...
2017-02-13 11:34:10.6787    ========================================
2017-02-13 11:34:10.6787    Import ends with error:
2017-02-13 11:34:10.6857    ========== Exception:
2017-02-13 11:34:10.6867    ContentRegistrationException: UnknownContentHandler: 'SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.ADSync.ADSettings'. ContentType: ADSettings
2017-02-13 11:34:10.8027       at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentType.SetFieldSlots(Type handlerType) in     c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentType.cs:line 549
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentType.Build(IXPathNavigable definitionXml) in     c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentType.cs:line 
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentType.set_Binary(BinaryData value) in     c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentType.cs:line 73
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentTypeManager.LoadOrCreateNew(IXPathNavigable contentTypeDefinitionXml) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentTypeManager.cs:line 309
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentTypeInstaller.Install(CTD ctd) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentTypeInstaller.cs:line 118
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentTypeInstaller.ExecuteBatch() in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentTypeInstaller.cs:line 106
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.InstallContentTypeDefinitionsAndAspects(String ctdPath, String aspectsPath) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line 389
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.Run(String schemaPath, String asmPath, String fsPath, String repositoryPath, Boolean validate, Boolean resetSecurity) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line 132
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.Importer.Main(String[] args) in c:\Builds\8\SenseNet\PACKAGEEvaluation\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\Importer.cs:line 115
```

Please advice,

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have the source edition. Please check that you compiled the code successfully and the Website\Tools folder contains many dlls. (although maybe it would be easier if you installed the web platform installer package.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. @MiklósTóth. I have this edition WITHOUT source code [link](http://download.sensenet.com/SenseNetEnterprise_Evaluation/sn-evaluation-webpi-6.5.3.8646.zip). Also, I do not have internet connection on my server to install SN via web platform installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import has imported Content that has a specified content handler that cannot be found. This "handler" is a DLL, and in this case it looks like you are missing the file "SenseNet.ContentRepository.dll" in your "Website\bin" and/or "Website\Tools" path, as this is the file that references ADSync.ADSettings in your error message.

If you are missing this DLL, then it's most likely that you are missing many more required files. If you had trouble compiling the project (it's BIG), then you can get the files from the WebPI installer. This is a lot trickier, as you need to use the SQL files to create your database first, and then unzip the files from the WebPI installer, and put them in the correct location.