# Module: PortalAuthentication Handler: ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to install SN evaluation edition on my machine (Win. Server 2012 R2 Datacenter) and I end with the following error:

[UnknownContentHandler Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203293/installing-sense-net-error-contentregistrationexception-unknowncontenthandler)

**I ignored above issue and tried to surf SN portal but got the following error message:**

[Screenshot of Detailed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umm1D.png)

Please advice,

Many thanks.

Comment: I tried troubleshooting the error by following this guide [link] (https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85); I got the following log file [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/93u95ezzgb5649k/SN_Failed_Req.rar). Please help me got the resolution to this error.

Comment: Dear @Miklós Tóth , Could you please check "XML failed request log" I attached in previous comment? Thanks,